# Embedded Groovy: How to use static type checking with external variables?

Tags: java, groovy, scripting, typechecking

I want to embed Groovy to enable scripting capabilities in my Java application. I want to use static type checking, and in addition I want to pass some additional (global) variables to the script. Here is my configuration:

```
    String script = "println(name)";  // this script was entered by the user

    // compiler configuration for static type checking
    CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
    config.addCompilationCustomizers(new ASTTransformationCustomizer(CompileStatic.class));

    // compile the script
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(config);
    Script script = shell.parse(script);

    // later, when we actually need to execute it...
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.setVariable("name", "John");
    script.setBinding(binding);
    script.run();
```

As you can see, the user-provided script uses the global variable `name`, which is injected via `script.setBinding(...)`. Now there is a problem:

- If I declare the variable `name` in the user script (e.g. `String name;`), then **the binding has no effect** because the variable already exists in the script.
- If I do not declare the variable in the script, the static type checker will (rightfully) complain that `name` was not declared.

**The question is:** how do I solve this? How can I tell the type checker that the script will receive a global variable of a certain type when it is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_a_dsl_for_type_checking),
You can use `extensions` parameter,

```
config.addCompilationCustomizers(
    new ASTTransformationCustomizer(
        TypeChecked,
        extensions:['robotextension.groovy'])
)
```

Then add *robotextension.groovy* to your classpath:

```
unresolvedVariable { var ->
    if ('name'==var.name) {
        storeType(var, classNodeFor(String))
        handled = true
    }
}
```

Here, we’re telling the compiler that if an *unresolved variable* is found and that the name of the variable is *name*, then we can make sure that the type of this variable is `String`.

Comment: I just want to add that it is possible to prepend the user script with something like `String name = this.binding.variables.name`, which also satisfies the typechecker. However, the downside is that modifying the user script will mess up the line numbers reported by the type checker, so your solution is most likely the better one.